# Meaning of refresh token using Bearer with TLS 1.2

Tags: jwt, authorization, token, access-token, bearer-token

I understand that when using Bearer you should be using two tokens access which has a short life time and refresh token which has a long life time. The reasoning behind that is that with every request you have to use the token and "more secure" is to use access token because when somebody get it he can use it only for a short period of time. And it's much higher chance that because you use refresh token once in a while nobody get's it. I understand that when you use simply http or https with crypto old certificates (tls 1.0 or 1.1) and there is a man in the middle this makes perfect.

But when you use new TLS... Is there really need for refresh token? Because with TLS and proper cert authorities there is no way to get access nor refresh token.

Or do I miss something?

Comment: Refresh token to use it for access token rotation to provide a better user experience, you would use the refresh token before the access token expire( I am not sure if you can still use it once you get 401 but I think you could )  to get the new access token and the new refresh token

Comment: Yeah but the whole think is that I think you can use just access token for both. You I would like to understand the real benefit of refresh token.

Comment: No you can't use access token to get a new access token, only refresh token to get a new access token and refresh token

Comment: Of course you can and we do it in our product also in many others.